# React изменить состояние одного элемента (handleClick)

Tags: reactjs

Добрый день, я новичок с React. Как изменить состояние только того (одного) элемента по которому кликаем? Есть такой код:

```
    class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Сейчас если запустить код и попробовать кликнуть по одному элементу, изменяться оба.

Comment: в state отдельную переменную для каждого элемента заведи

Comment: А можешь пожалуйста на примере?

Comment: запостил ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {buttonStatus: [true, true]};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    const newStatus = this.state.buttonStatus.slice();
    newStatus[i] = !this.state.buttonStatus[i];
    this.setState({buttonStatus: newStatus});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(0)}>
        {this.state.buttonStatus[0] ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(1)}>
        {this.state.buttonStatus[1] ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```